# DFS to find connectivity in a adjacency list of vectors of structs

Tags: struct, depth-first-search, adjacency-list

I've made an adjacency list, which is a vector that contains many node structures that each contain 2 numbers. They're formatted such that Vertex 1 that is connected to verticies 2 and 3 create structs 1,2 and 2,1 as well as 1,3 and 3,1. How would I go about checking the connectivity of this adjacency list using DSF?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear in which language you want to do this, so I will try to give some pseudocode.

```
1  adj <- [(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1)] // Adjacency list
2  S <- {} // Stack that keeps track of vertices that are discovered
3  for each vertex v:
4    visited[v] = false
5  S.push(v)
6  while S not empty:
7    u <- S.pop()
8    if visited[u] == false:
9      visited[u] = true // Found a new vertex, let's explore
10     for each edge in adj: 
11       if edge[0] = u: // If this is the first vertex of an edge
12         S.push(edge[1]) // We add the neighbor to the stack of 'to-explore' vertices
```

After this algorithm you could loop over the adjacency list and check if the first part of the struct is in the discovered list (If one of the 2 vertices connected by an edge is in the discovered list, so must the other)

You could make this more efficient by changing the adjacency list so that all 'duplicate' structs get removed, so changing `[(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1)]` to `[(1,2), (1,3)]`. Then change line 11 to check for both `edge[0]` and `edge[1]`, and pushing the other one. This way the for-loops will only be half as long.

Comment: Apologies- it's in C++. However, I think I'll be able to solve it with the psuedocode you gave me. Thank you!